# HTML input multiplication using JS is having issue with multiple PHP sql query

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table in database with single row as some value in it.

I been trying to write a sql query in a way along with HTML 3 input boxes which one takes input number from user and multiplies it with other default number in input box 2 and prints it out in input box 3.

I wrote JS code for it and it works fine. now i added php to it, in a way it input box 1 takes value directly from php table row and multiplies it with user inserted value in box2

It still works fine, but when there are two rows i the given table, it does not work for second value. it doesn't multiplies while the first value gets multiplied.

My Php , Js, Html code goes as:

```
<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = '$number'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {   
?>
<input type="number" name="input1" id="input1" default value="<?php echo $row2['price']; ?>" readonly> 
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="0">
<input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="">

<script>
    $("#input2,#input1").keyup(function () {
    $('#output').val($('#input1').val() * $('#input2').val());
});
</script>
```

As i mentioned it works perfectly fine with single row in table, but when i add another row with another value, it prints out another column with input 1 , 2,3 but doesn't work with multiplication,...

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: *Note*: If the PHP isn't needed just provide the parsed HTML, this will make it much easier for us to see the problem without having to assume code. Although from looking based on what you have there are duplicate id's if the loop iterates more than once, id selection will only get the first one in that case.

Comment: if you add another row, the name or id of the textbox not changing, this will cause error, change  textbox id's / name dynamically

Comment: how do i do that @ManzoorSamad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you will be creating elements with duplicate `id`'s, in the case there are several of the same id's on the page the [id-selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) will on get the first one in the DOM.

> If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

One solution is to have each loop modify the id given to be unique for each iteration, such as changing `id="input1"` into `id="input1_<?php echo index; ?>"` where `index` would be from `0` to `n-1`. Or you could use the unique column or PK of the record: `id="input1_<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>"`. You would need to modify the id-selector in all cases with this approach.

---

Another probably cleaner way to do this is have only a single script and use `class` (instead of `id`'s) or `name` as the selectors and give each group a parent instead. Then you could modify the `output` item based on the shared parent node of the `input1` and `input2`. Here is an example of that:

```js
$(".input2,.input1").keyup(function () {
    $output = $(this).parent().find(".output");
    $input1 = $(this).parent().find(".input1");
    $input2 = $(this).parent().find(".input2");
    $output.val($input1.val() * $input2.val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <!-- first record -->
  <input type="number" name="input1" class="input1" value="0" /> 
  <input type="text" name="input2" class="input2" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="output" class="output" value="" />
</div>
<div> <!-- second record -->
  <input type="number" name="input1" class="input1" value="0" /> 
  <input type="text" name="input2" class="input2" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="output" class="output" value="" />
</div>
```